# Interpolate irregular grid to regular grid

Tags: r, interpolation

I have an irregular grid, that I need to convert to a regular grid to take advantage of `image`'s `useRaster=TRUE` option for graphics devices. I can do this on a small scale by converting the irregular grid to points, then interpolate the points using akima's `interp`. However this scales horribly with larger dimensions, so I'm looking for options.

First, here is the small scale (5x10) example, where only the x-dimension is irregular:

```
nx <- 5
ny <- 10
si <- list()  # irregular surface
si$x <- cumsum(runif(nx) * 10) + 100
si$y <- seq(20, 50, length.out=ny)
si$z <- matrix(rnorm(nx * ny), ncol=ny)
image(si)
```

[image: irregular]

And the bilinear interpolated result:

```
sr_x <- seq(min(si$x), max(si$x), length.out=nx * 5)
sr_y <- si$y  # this dimension is already regular
require(akima)  # interpolate from points repeated off irregular grid
sr <- interp(rep(si$x, length(si$y)), rep(si$y, each=length(si$x)), si$z,
             xo=sr_x, yo=sr_y)
image(sr, useRaster=TRUE)
```

[image: regular]

However, if a larger dimension irregular grid is used (e.g. `nx <- 50; ny <- 100`), the procedure is really slow. Is there either a library or technique that would speed up the process?

---

**Update and possibly a solution.** The data describes time vs time (both in years), where the irregular dimension has timesteps between 0.5 days to 30 days, and the second time axis has equal-spaced 365 day spacings. Since the spacings are much smaller along the irregular axis, interpolating will not work. Thus a smoothing or aggregating method will yield better results.

A more realistic data scenario, showing the finer irregular dimension:

```
nx <- 200
ny <- 10
si <- list()  # irregular surface
si$x <- cumsum(runif(nx, 0.5, 30) / 365)
si$y <- 1:ny
si$z <- matrix(rnorm(nx * ny), ncol=ny)
image(si)
```

[image: irregular_2]

And some really crude aggregate means:

```
dx <- 1/12  # 1 month spacing along x-axis
sr <- list()  # regular surface
sr$x <- seq(min(si$x), max(si$y), dx)  # equal-width breaks
nsrx <- length(sr$x)
sr$y <- si$y  # this dimension is already regular
sr$z <- matrix(nrow=length(sr$x), ncol=length(sr$y))
# Classify irregular dimension
si_xc <- cut(si$x, sr$x, include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE)
# Aggregate means from irregular to regular dimension
for(xi in seq_len(nsrx))
    sr$z[xi,] <- apply(si$z[si_xc == xi, , drop=FALSE], 2, mean)
image(sr, zlim=range(si$z), useRaster=TRUE)
```

This seems to do the trick, and scales on much larger datsets with 100s of years along each dimension. So I suppose my new question would be simply to tidy up the above code to perform aggregate means.

[image: regular_2]

Comment: What is the real data source? Something in netcdf? It can be worth investigating

Comment: @mdsumner time vs age, both dimensions have units of years. z is probability along age.

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages w/ "kriging" tools, which is basically what you want. However, I dunno whether it'll be any faster than what `akima::interp` does.

I solved this using multicore techniques, so if you have a multicore processor, consider something similar to the following code snippet:

```
picbits <- clusterApply( myclus, 1:length(picsec) , function(j) { gc(); 
akima::interp(newx[picsec[[j]] ], newy[picsec[[j]] ], picture[picsec[[j]] ], 

xo=trunc(min(newx[picsec[[j]] ])):trunc(max(newx[picsec[[j]] ])), 

yo=trunc(min(newy[picsec[[j]] ])):trunc(max(newy[picsec[[j]] ])) )} )
```

That is extracted from a function I wrote to perform a rotational "swirl" on an image, so there's a lot of cruft there you won't need.